# Nested JOIN query in Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to write an **Hibernate** 4 nested join query but I can't manage to obtain what I want.

I have the classes `ProductDetail`, `Product` and `Feedback`. In both `ProductDetail` and `Feedback` I have an attribute `product` that references to the relative `Product`.

So separately I may easily obtain joins like this:

First join:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ProductDetail d
LEFT JOIN d.product p
```

Second join:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Feedback f
LEFT JOIN f.product p
```

How can I put those joins together?

I tried this:

```
FROM ProductDetail d
LEFT JOIN d.product p
RIGHT JOIN Feedback f
```

But whenever I try to put something on the right side of a JOIN that is not a path (e.g. `d.product`) I get the following error:

> antlr.SemanticException: Path expected for join!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
FROM Product p, ProductDetail pd, Feedback f where p = pd.product and p = f.product
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried already this and it results in a nested INNER JOIN! What I need is a nested LEFT JOIN :(